# How to fix Dependency resolution Error in android studio related to android.gms:play-services:12.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Everything was working perfect until I implemented play-services:12.0.1 to my app module. Tried changing the versions of play-services but nothing helps. Before implementing, it was working perfectly.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' }
```

Following is the error :

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
```

There are more lines of error. I guess some kind of issue is there with firebase

Comment: First of all remove implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

Comment: But I need that to use FusedLocationProviderClient. I tried removing that but then there was error in FusedLocationProviderClient.

Comment: Add com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0 or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

and add single modules you need. In your case:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

You should also update (for androidx compatibility)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```